# Correctly parallelising lots of little tasks within a method using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm implementing image processing algorithms in C# using .NET Framework 4.72 and need to decrease the computation code. Overall the code is sequential but there are quite a few methods with parameters that do not depend on each other. For example, it might be something like this

```
public void Algorithm(Object x, Object y) {    
    x = Filter(x);
    x = Morphology(x);
    y = Filter(y);
    y = Morphology(y);
    var z = Add(x,y);

    //Similar pattern of separate operation that are then combined.
}
```

These functions generally take around 100ms to 500ms. They can be parallelised, and my approach has been something like this:

```
public void Algorithm(Object x, Object y) {  
    var xTask = Task.Run(() => {
        x = Filter(x);
        x = Morphology(x);
    });
    var yTask = Task.Run(() => {
        y = Filter(y);
        y = Morphology(y);
    });
    Task.WaitAll(xTask, yTask);
    var z = Add(x,y);
}
```

It seems to work, a similar bit of code runs approximately twice as fast. (Note that the whole thing is wrapped in another `Task.Run` in the top most level function, so that is why I'm not `await`ing here.

Question: Is this a valid approach, or is there another method for parallelising lots of little method calls that is more safe or efficient?

Update: This is not for parallelising processing a batch of images. It is about processing a single image as quick as possible.

Comment: try to explore Task.Factory for more detailed task creation. Also try to explore the shared context in tasks. I don't know what x,y,z is. If it is a reference type object then this code is a killer in parallel/multithread programming

Comment: Try [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Parallel.ForEach( //do stuff )?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop  Literally designed for easy parallel operations :)

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks - TPL DataFlow looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid enough - if you can process your workload in parallel then you should.  You just need to be very aware of WHEN your workload can and should be parallel - and when it needs to be performed in order.

You also need to consider the cost of creating a new task, versus the benefits of doing so (i.e. sometimes avoid very small, very fast tasks).

I would strongly recommend you create additional methods and collections for managing your tasks - when they complete, and handle running lots of separate sets in parallel.  Avoiding locking, managing shared memory/variables etc.  For example, are you only ever processing one image at a time, or can you start processing the next one if you have cores available?

You need to be very careful with Task.WaitAll() - obviously you need to draw all your work together at some point, but be careful not to lock or block other work.

There's lots of articles out there on the various patterns you can use (pipelines sounds like a good match here).

Here's a few starters:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/tpl-and-traditional-async-programming

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism

Comment: When processing a set of images I normally put all the work in `Parallel.ForEach` etc. In this case, the program interacts with a machine which waits on the result of the image processing before it can continue, so I have to try to parallelise within the method as much as possible.